# what is mpic++ file used for?

Tags: compiler-construction, build, g++, mpich, mpic++

I want to know what is '/usr/bin/mpic++' file used for.

I build mpich2 using g++4.5.4, and mpic++ script default link to g++4.5.4.

Then, I update g++ to g++4.7.

My question is that 'Do I need to recompile mpich using g++4.7 or just modify the mpic++ script'?

Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that `mpic++` is broken on Ubuntu 20.04 because it of a missing symlink to `libmpi.so`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540047/cannot-find-lmpi-when-compiling-openmpi-code/1248522#1248522

Answer (score 2):

mpic++ is a wrapper script around your C++ compiler for compiling/linking MPI programs. Rebuilding mpich2 with the new g++ is a good idea, since configure may detect different configuration in the compiler that could change the wrapper script.