# How should I build MPI C++ programs with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, mpi

I've not used MPI before - and frankly, I'm not really using it now, but I need to convert a Makefile which builds an MPI program into a CMakeLists.txt for a subdirectory of a project of mine. I'm wondering how to do this, given that it's apparently customary to invoke the compiler different for MPI C++ programs (`mpic++`).

How should I build an MPI program using CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's not that complicated after all:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo MPI::MPI_CXX)
```

But you might still need to use `mpi_run` to run your program.

I'm still not sure about the use of mpic++. The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739909/what-is-mpic-file-used-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) claims it's just a wrapper script, but - it is *not* a wrapper script on my system.